# How to upload to remote machine with JSPSmartUpload?

Tags: jsp

I am able to upload files to local machine using JSPSmartUpload, but I am not able to upload to a remote machine. It throws the following exception:

> com.jspsmart.upload.SmartUploadException:File can't be saved(1120).
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:./Manfile.csv(No such file or directory)SBL

How can I solve it? I am using Tomcat.

Comment: Just curious, where did you get JSPSmartUpload from? Inherited a dusty 90's project? JSPSmartUpload is dead for ages. The current de facto standard is Apache Commons FileUpload.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map/mount the remote disk on the local machine so that it's available the usual `java.io.File` way. If mapping/mounting is not an option, then the only option left is setting up a FTP server on the remote machine and use a FTP client to send it. Apache Commons Net has a FTP client.